# Twig filter to convert special characters to URL friendly characters

Tags: templating, localization, filter

I have a text field that will accept some German text in it as a headline of a section. I'm using Craft's `|kebab` filter to turn that into a lowercase-with-dashes id that my navigation scrolls down to when its corresponding link is clicked.

However, when there's a word like "Über Uns", the umlaut Ü stays in the output like so: "über-uns" and this messes up my javascript so the scrolling doesn't work for that one item. Is there a filter or something to have it be output to "ueber-uns"?

Answer (score 2):

My first idea would be to use the `url_encode` filter than would turn your special characters into a URL friendly format. I imagine these would also be Javascript friendly.

If you'd like to convert the characters to something like "ueber-uns" maybe take a look at the `convert_encoding` [filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/convert_encoding.html) in Twig. It uses a function called [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

I tried to find what encoding you'd need to use to convert `Ü` to something javascript friendly but was only able print even more obscure characters.

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks I was aware of the filter but couldn't get it to work before because I couldn't figure out the correct to/from arguments.  I did a bunch of google searches but it doesn't output what I'm looking for, possible because "ue" is not really a character?  Dunno.  Encoding is always a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: Just a thought - do you need the character to be replaced or could you remove it? Just found this answer that removes special characters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8171868

Comment: I suppose it could just be removed since it's an ID just in the code, but it would be nice to have it be replaced, since then I could technically use it in urls, etc.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?